# How to check the array of featured images IDs

Tags: post-thumbnails, array, id

I'm trying to show some specific text on top of the featured images depending on their IDs. Some of the featured images will have the same text.

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

if($post_thumbnail_id =='2030') {
echo '<span>Location</span>';
}
```

How do I check the array of $post_thumbnail_id?

The following example does not work.

```
if($post_thumbnail_id == array('1000','2000'))
```

Comment: Looking for `in_array()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solely a PHP question. But as birgire mentioned, you can use `in_array()`. So, change your code to this:

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

if( in_array( $post_thumbnail_id, array(1, 2, 3 ) ) ) {
    echo '<span>Location</span>';
}
```

The first argument is your value, the second one is the array you want to search in.